# File Upload With Progress Bar in MVC

Tags: c#-3.0

I have done the file upload process in MVC asp.net, Now i want show a Progress bar as file upload takes pretty much time..

Please let me know how to implement progress bar using Jquery or something like UpdatePanel. and i want to implement it with the same existing code in MVC .

Comment: [Ajax Multiple file upload script with Progress bar](http://lesson8.blogspot.com/2012/09/ajax-multiple-file-upload-script-with.html)

Answer (score 1):

I suggest go with Uploadify: http://www.uploadify.com/

I used it before for one MVC project, it's very convenient and it's more powerful than just a progress bar, only with few simple code and then you can make it happen.

Or you can try to do it yourself with this: http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/290359/Multiple-File-upload-in-mvc3-with-progress-bar

Comment: i have checked the Uploadify.. But its done using Flash. i was unable to do it in my project..

Comment: is there any direct way to implement the progress bar, instead of all these jquery Uploaders.. like Update Panel in Asp.net..

Comment: Please let me know is there any direct way to implement Progress bar, That Display the Percentage Upload done from DataBase. When Uploading is going on ....